# Can't submit form with custom submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I've posted this question yesterday too, but to no avail.
I'm really new to PHP and I have no idea what I'm doing. I thoroughly researched my issue but can't find anything that solves the problem while maintaining the actual blue button, instead of the default "Submit"-button. In my PHP I used human certification from a template, but when I try to delete it, it gives me an error.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="myform">

                        <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Naam*'/>

                        <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 Email" name='email' placeholder='Email*'/>

                        <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='subject' placeholder='Onderwerp'/>

                        <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='message' placeholder='Bericht*'></textarea>

                        <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
                            <ul>

                                <li class="clear"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').reset();"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Leeg</a></li>

                                <li class="send"><i class="fa fa-share" id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="send"></i>Verstuur</li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
    $to = 'mymail@mail.com'; 

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['send']) {                
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Uw bericht is vestuurd!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Bericht niet verstuurd. Stuur een email naar mymail@mail.com</p>'; 
    } 
    } else if ($_POST['send']) {
    echo '<p>U heeft de anti-spam vraag verkeerd ingevuld!</p>';
    }
?>
```

[This is what it looks like currently.](http://i.imgur.com/BcXFhnb.png)
The button with "Verstuur" doesn't do anything for some reason.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Changed it to type="submit". It still doesn't work. :/

CSS:

```
.forma .cBtn .clear , .cBtn .send{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    padding-left: 17px

}
.forma .cBtn .clear  a, .cBtn .send a{
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 700;
}
.forma .cBtn .send{
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #179abf;
    background:#1fcdff ;
}
.forma .cBtn .send:hover{
    background:#2f2f2f;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #000 ;
}
```

Comment: Change the type attribute from "send" to "submit" in your "i" next to "Verstuur". Insert the "</i>" after "Verstuur" and not before. [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: I don't see a "submit button" in this code...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The button now has a different font like [this](http://i.imgur.com/1IVVGuC.png), but still does nothing.

@David. The "Submit button" is the "Verstuur" button.

Comment: @Jasper: That's not a button, that's just text.  You might want to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP and HTML forms.  To submit the form you need an `input type="submit"` element, or you need to use JavaScript to manually submit the form.

Comment: @David. I changed it to input type="submit" but it still doesn't work. I understand that I can spend hours on finding out how PHP works, but I just want this easy contact form to work so I can move on honestly.

Comment: @Jasper: You're going to have to be more specific than "it doesn't work".  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here or debug the code on your computer for you.  Describe the problem.

Comment: @David Sorry. Whenever I fill out the contact sheet with test and click on the submit button, it does nothing. The contact sheet isn't cleared, I don't get feedback like "You're message has been send" or do I get an e-mail at all.

Comment: @Jasper: a submit button on a form "does nothing" then either your HTML code is incorrect and it's not a valid form or button, or your web browser is completely broken.  At the very least submitting a form should send a POST request to the server and direct you to the target page.

Comment: @David That's what I thought, but I can't find any mistakes in my HTML code. I've tried various 'solutions', but they all create a new, standard submit-button within the original button.

Comment: @Jasper: `"they all create a new, standard submit-button within the original button"` - It's becoming less and less clear what you're even asking at this point.  The HTML posted in the question doesn't have a submit button and needs one, that much is clear.  The form not submitting, PHP not being installed, creating "buttons within buttons"... These things are not clear.  You're going to need to be specific in order for anybody to help you.  "Nothing is working right" just doesn't describe an answerable question.

Comment: @David. The solutions thus far give me [Photo1](http://i.imgur.com/1vLblQn.png) or [Photo2](http://i.imgur.com/IIG1Px0.png). In both cases, the grey button is the button that works and redirects me to the PHP page (Because Dreamweaver doesn't support it like you said). I want to have it look like [Photo3](http://i.imgur.com/BcXFhnb.png) and have the blue button with "Verstuur" be the button that actually works.

Comment: @Jasper post your CSS and we can work out why your button looks wrong, but the HTML code I have provided is valid and should fix part of your problem.

Comment: @Jasper: Then you'll need to either style the button to look like you want it to look or use JavaScript to respond to a non-button element's click event and submit the form in the JavaScript code.  Just because you *want* some random text in your HTML to be a button doesn't make it a button.  The browser is expecting you to click *a submit button*, it isn't expecting you to click *something blue*.

Comment: @PiranhaGeorge Updated the OP with CSS code. It's all from a template that I'm using, so don't judge.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
<li class="send"><i class="fa fa-share" id="send" name="send" type="send" value="send"></i>Verstuur</li>
```

to this:

```
<li class="send"><input type="submit" id="send" name="submit" value="Verstuur" class="fa fa-share" /></li>
```

Edit: here's a beginner tutorial about HTML forms http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/forms/

Edit: moving the send class should improve your button styling

```
<li><input type="submit" id="send" name="submit" value="Verstuur" class="send fa fa-share" /></li>
```

Edit: here's a fiddle with some improved CSS http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGeorge/x27f9sr6/

Comment: Thanks for your time. It now looks like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/eb1c999d74f9d772baf2afc9bd4bdab1.png) with the grey button redirecting me a page with the PHP on it rather then executing the PHP code.

Comment: @Jasper: If you're seeing the PHP code in your browser then PHP isn't installed or configured correctly on your web server.

Comment: @David I'm doing all this in Dreamweaver and using F12 to get a visual idea in my browser. Do I actually need to have the site online to test the PHP?

Comment: @Jasper: At the very least you need something that will interpret and execute the PHP code.  If Dreamweaver doesn't do that then use something that does.  Something like, perhaps, PHP: http://us3.php.net/downloads.php